# Plone app crashes immediately on launch - how to get useful error output?

Tags: python, plone

I installed Plone, added some packages to my `buildout.cfg`, and ran `bin/buildout` successfully. However, now, when I run `bin/instance restart`, it crashes immediately with no error output:

```
$ bin/instance restart
. 
daemon process restarted, pid=29508
$ ps aux | grep 29508
ubuntu   29626  0.0  0.0  12944   928 pts/0    S+   11:52   0:00 grep --color=auto 29508
$ ps aux | grep plone
ubuntu   29743  0.0  0.0  12944   984 pts/0    S+   11:53   0:00 grep --color=auto plone
```

There's also nothing in `var/log/instance.log` besides an entry indicating that the server *started*:

```
------
2018-02-08T11:53:24 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Thu Feb  8 11:53:24 2018
    Hostname: 0.0.0.0
    Port: 8080
```

How can I find out what caused the crash?

Comment: Sorry, this is a duplicate. Plone has been around for a long time. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Dang. I wonder how to get that dupe more Google Juice; lots of searching for *plone crashes on launch* and similar variants got me basically nothing.

Comment: I used the site search with `[plone] fg is:a`. Domain knowledge, I guess.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure, but that's clearly not a useful search to somebody who doesn't already know about `fg`, which is the audience that needs to find it.

Comment: Which is why we keep duplicates around; more google juice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed - perhaps this question of mine will yet turn out to help people despite being a dupe. I can hope, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running `bin/instance restart`, use:

```
bin/instance fg
```

This runs Plone in [debug mode](https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/getstarted/debug_mode.html) in the foreground, instead of in production mode via Supervisor.

You'll then likely see an error message and traceback for your crash, (hopefully hinting at a missing dependency or other easily-soluble problem).